# High-level overview of package installation, which ones have custom configs, and the config locations

Tags: package-management

I'm often lost when dealing with my package ecosystem. I was wondering, is there some way to achieve a high-level overview that tells me which packages I've installed over the default ones, along with information concerning their configs, i.e., if they have a custom one, and their location?

Comment: I do not understand "*which packages I've installed over the default ones*." Are you asking about non-Ubuntu packages with higher (or lower) versions than stock Ubuntu? Or are you asking something else? Custom configs should generally be located in /etc.